# Is there any way to prepare some HTTP request and execute them later with Angular?

Tags: angular, http, request

I want to prepare some HTTP requests and after doing some things I want to execute them. For example:

```
this.requests.push(this.serviceExample.get())
..... // some things
this.request.executeRequests()
```

I've been searching on Internet but I was not able to find anything. I don't know if it is possible with Angular.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to do some requests but I don't want to execute. I want to execute them in a generic component wich has to receive the requests to execute.

Comment: Are you trying to create a pipeline? As in, I want these requests to execute in this order and I want all of them to be executed at a specified time?

Comment: @KylerJohnson in fact, the order doesn't matter. I just want to prepare it in a component and pass through another one to execute them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.
Angular `HttpClient` requests are not executed until they are subscribed to. You can subscribe to all using `forkJoin`.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

executeRequests() { 
    forkJoin(...this.requests).subscribe()
}
```